Touchpad not working after using logitech USB mouse
I am working on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, on a laptop HP EliteBook 840.
My touchpad was working OK up to today. Now, it's not working at all, I cannot click or move the mouse.
My only possible explanation is the use of Logitech Mouse/Keybord (connected via USB-bluetooth) that I used for the first time today. I tried rebooting, this does not solve the issue. Any idea ?
